# Generate Random Numbers In A Range with All Numbers Being Hit

Tags: java

I want to generate random integers from range 0-9 and put it in an array of **size 100**.  That's easy but I'm clueless on how to make sure that in the array, I have at least one occurrence of every integer in the range 0-9.

This is all using java by the way.

This is what I've got so far (the numbers are different in my coding because I wanted to ask a simpler question):

```
public static int[] extendTo1024(int[] key) {
    int[] extendedKey = new int[1024];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        int rand = random.nextInt(64) + 1;
        extendedKey[i] = bitKey[rand];
    }
    return extendedKey;
}
```

Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First please show what you have done to achieve this!

Comment: Just add 10 items from 0 to 9, generate the remaining 90 and then shuffle the array.

Comment: If the integers in the array were generated randomly there would always be a small but non-zero chance that at least one of the integers in the range was not present in the array. Therefore, do I understand correctly that you are looking for a way to generate integers that is not actually random? If so, it would be helpful if you could describe the required characteristics of this non-random sequence of integers in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: @Arun I have edited to reflect this!

Comment: @Simon It's not truly random, you're correct.  The characteristics for my array should be this - 1. Array must contain all numbers in the range and 2. the numbers put into the array are in randomized order.  Hope that helps you understand it a bit more.

Comment: You're saying you have an array of size 100 and numbers from 0-9, but in the source code you posted you have an array of size 1024 and numbers 1 to 64. That doesn't add up. Please update your question or your code.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Does it really matter? The question can be generalized to a set of K symbols and an array of N elements where K < N without any change in meaning nor solution.

Comment: StackOverflow is about high quality questions and answers that will be useful for people who have a similar problem. Having code and a question that don't match is not a good sign IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fill the first 10 elements with numbers 0-9
2. Fill the rest with random numbers
3. Shuffle the array

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Actually Jack beat me by 3 minutes. But for some reason he commented on the OP instead of answering.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the other post, I want the first 10 cells of the array to be random also meaning that something like this could happen in the first 10 cells {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}.

Comment: @Tony, that's why there's step 3 for that.

Comment: Oh okay I understand it! Thank you :) so I should write a method that shuffles the array after its been filled?

Comment: @Tony: See the answer to [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//make sure the array contains all occurences of 0-9
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    al.add(i, i);
}

//generate random number for the remaining 90
for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 10);            
    al.add(i, random);
}

//shuffle the random numbers to make sure that the first 10 are randomly placed
Collections.shuffle(al);

//Convert it back to array (In case you need it to be array not ArrayList)
Integer[] randomNums = al.toArray(new Integer[100]);

//result
for (int i : randomNums) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, I really appreciate it :) but I want the first 10 arrays to also be randomly generated as well alongside with the other 90.